# Android databinding: cannot find ...BindingImpl in generated databinding file

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding, android-jetpack

I am trying to databind a viewmodel using the example project android-sunflower. The current issue is that when I am trying to build the project I get the error `error: cannot find symbol symbol:   class FragmentShopBindingImpl
  location: package {{packageName}}.databinding` in the class `DataBindinMapperImpl`
I'm not really sure what I am missing here, since I added everything from the example project. The class `FragmentShopBindingImpl` does not get generated, or shouldn't it? Since I cannot see any occurence of a class ending with 'Impl' in the android sunflower example
My code:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val factory = InjectorUtils.provideShopViewModelFactory(context!!)
        val shopViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)
            .get(ShopViewModel::class.java)

        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentShopBinding>(
            inflater, R.layout.fragment_shop, container, false).apply {
            viewModel = shopViewModel
            lifecycleOwner = this@ShopFragment
        }

        return binding.root
    }
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="{{packageName}}.viewmodel.ShopViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".fragments.ShopFragment">

        <TextView
            android:text="@{viewModel}"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Image of generated file (ignore the {{packageName}}:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: cannot find symbol import com.gourav.news.databinding.ActivityDetailBindingImpl;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54696338/error-cannot-find-symbol-import-com-gourav-news-databinding-activitydetailbindi)

Comment: Will check it if I have the time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems the only thing I had to add was `<import type="android.view.View" />`
 in the data tags...

Answer (score 8):

In your xml code inside textView tag, for android:text attribute you have used @{viewmodel}. It just refers your shopViewModel class, you must target the text variable inside that class. Then the gen. class file errors will vanish.

> bindingImpl errors are mostly generated for invalid
>   assignment for XML-text or XML-onClick attributes.

Answer (score 4):

If you use two-ways databinding (`@={myBindingValue}`, with the **'='** sign instead of `@{myBindingValue}`) sometimes, you'll have this unusefull generic error because the value you are trying to bind is declared as immutable => **val** instead of **var** in Kotlin in your data class.

**Exemple :**

```
data class User(
   val name,
   var email
)
```

In this example, you could bind the user's email variable as : `text="@={myViewModel.user.email}"`
But, if you try to bind the user's name : `text="@={myViewModel.user.name}"` you will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define variable as ObservableField below :

```
 public final ObservableField<String> name = new ObservableField<>();
 public final ObservableField<String> family = new ObservableField<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error show up but it was because my `android:text="@={...}"` was outside the editText.

Answer (score 0):

I had a `BindingAdapter` tag that was present in an *unreachable* module.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was , there were multiple qualifier layout's for example I had one for Night Mode and the base file, I was only making changes in the base file but not in other qualifier resource file, once I made the changes in all qualifiers, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message but the problem is different. Although I see that OP's problem had been solved, the same error message may often pop up when playing with the MVVM architecture. (I'm giving my answer in Java btw, but the problems can be solved in the similar manner)

Basically, when this error message

```
error: cannot find symbol symbol:   class FragmentShopBindingImpl
  location: package {{packageName}}.databinding
```

pop up, it doesn't tell you anything about what's wrong. It pops up when the compiler failed to generate the `xxxBindingImpl` class (which should have been auto-generated) due to some issues with your binding.

For my case, inspecting the actual source of error by running `./gradlew :app:build --stacktrace` helped a lot, and mostly it's one of the following problems:

1. Name crashes in your xml (particularly, when you have multiple views with the same id that require the same binding class.)
2. Some attributes don't have default binding adapters, e.g. `android:layout_width` and `android:src`. In this case you'll need to set up the binding adapter for the attribute yourself by adding `@BindingAdapter` tag:

```
    @BindingAdapter("android:src") //<-----
    public static void setIcon(ImageView view, int drawable){ view.setImageResource(drawable); }
```

3. Missing imports:
   When you're using classes that are not one of the primitive types in the xml, you must import the class with FULL PATH as follows:

```
    <data class="BoxBinding">
        <import type="android.view.View"/>  //<-----
        <variable
            name="boxData"
            type="{{packageName}}.views.boxlists.BoxList.BoxData" />
    </data>
```