# DataBinding error: cannot find symbol import com.example.project_name.package_name

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to implement dataBinding in my project. After adding layout tags AND trying to declare data with variables, android studio says that cannot find my class. I'm using main_activity to store recyclerView and second xml for imageView. What I'm missing?

main_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_with_recycleView_ID"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

single_picture.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="picture"
            type="com.example.recycleviewpictures.Requests.Responsnes.Pictures" />
    </data>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/single_picture_id"/>

</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Check the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54696338/error-cannot-find-symbol-import-com-gourav-news-databinding-activitydetailbindi/54699538

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it looks like the problem was in naming packages. You can not name them with capital leters, because Android Studio treat them like classes.

Comment: More clarification >  DataBinding classes must start with a capital letter and the package names should be started with a simple letter. Otherwise Data-Binding fails with "couldn't make a guess"

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

- In Android Studio in your Build tab check which gradle task failed:
  [image]
- Select the "Gradle" tab on the top right of Android Studio:
  [image]
- Find the gradle task that failed and double-click it:
  [image]
- Let the gradle task finish and look at the output. It should say "FAILED" and some lines above that it should tell you what the problem is:
  [image]